# Iframe button trouble

Tags: html, button, iframe

My first question here. I'll try to explain my situation in the best possible way (with the same blindfolds I have with their system).

My client have a setup where on their homepage www.example.com (index.html) have an iframe that holds the main content except the main navigation. I have access to change the content in their iframe page, called "home_content.html"

In the main navigation on index.html there is a link to a user login page www.example.com/login. When the user logs in, it redirects back to the page the user previously was on. So if I'm on www.example.com, click and go to www.example.com/login, login, I then return back to www.example.com

My issue is that If I place a link in my iframe page pointing to the login page, when logged in. It returns me to the iframe url = www.example.com/home_content.html rather then back to "Home" www.example.com

Is there a way for me with only access to home_content.html be able to "trick" the system to think that the link clicked here actually comes from index.html so that when redirected back after signing in I simply return to www.example.com?

Sorry if this is a bit unclear. Basically I want a click from an iframe to be registered as if it was clicked from its parent.

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
Chris

Comment: How about using target="_parent" in the link on the button? This opens the  new page in the parent frame.

Comment: What do you have so far? You could set up the link for the login page so using jq/js to get the current url and save it to memory, json or something then have the login button or whatever use said url to return. If you haven't done any work on it yet do some googling, work on it then post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm using <base target="_parent" /> in the head of the iframe page so that links load in the parent frame.

Comment: I don't have access to the login button on the login page if that is what you mean CalebB?

Comment: @ChrisEriksson you should tag the people you are repliying too, otherwise they won't be notified! Just mention their user name: *@*chris or *@*ChrisEriksson will both work. (remove the * )